# Remove # from url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a project using reactjs.In my project i want to remove # from the url. Currently i am using the react-router version 4. here is my code

```
 import { HashRouter as Router, Route,browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
<Router history={browserHistory} >
  <App>
    <Route  path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/revenue" component={RevenueReports} />
</App>
 </Router>,
```

Comment: Maybe don't use HashRouter as Router if you don't want to route with hashes in the URL.

Comment: Use `BrowserRouter` instead of `HashRouter`.  You don't need to explicitly set `browserHistory` with `BrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 1):

browserHistory is not available in latest react-router-dom. However `BrowserRouter` uses the default as `browserHistory` and you could simply do

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
<Router >
  <App>
    <Route  path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/revenue" component={RevenueReports} />
  </App>
</Router>,
```

According to the docs:

> A `BrowserRouter` is a `<Router>` that uses the HTML5 history API
>   (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in
>   sync with the URL.